# load remote url in angular route loadchildren

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-elements, ngx-build-plus

I am trying to load a lazy-loaded application from a server

> localhost://4600

inside a client application

> localhost://3000

as an angular-element using ngx-build-plus, but when I load the angular element it fetches chunks using the client url(localhost://3000) instead of the server url. is it possible to fetch the chunk files from the server((localhost://4600)
the code in the server

```
{
path: 'settings',
loadChildren: async () => import('./settings/settings.module').then(m => m.SettingsModule)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for those facing similar issue webpack  **publicPath** was able to solve this for me.
the below code was added to my webpack file

```
output: {
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:4600/',
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: "[name].[contenthash].bundle.js"
    }
```

for more info on [publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/)